# Javascript Permutations magic trick

Tags: javascript, permutation

I'm reading some algorithms to try and understand permutations in javascript, and the following one quite stunned me

```
var permArr = [], usedChars = [];
function permute(input) {
  var i, ch, chars = input.split('');
  for (i = 0; i < chars.length; i++) {
    ch = chars.splice(i, 1);
    usedChars.push(ch);
    if (chars.length == 0) permArr[permArr.length] = usedChars.join('');
    permute(chars.join(""));
    chars.splice(i, 0, ch);
    usedChars.pop();
  }
  return permArr
}
```

FYI I found this algorithm on the following website: http://staff.roguecc.edu/JMiller/JavaScript/permute.html

I can see that this algorithm works, but there is a line that confuses me and I can't find anywhere where it works

```
var i, ch, chars = input.split("");
```

If i console.log(i) or console.log(ch) before OR after in the code, it returns undefined everywhere.
If i remove i and ch, the algorithm does not work anymore.

Can someone explain me this line and how it works?
Thanks a lot

Comment: The line that confuses you has a name: "Javascript multiple left-hand assignment".  Also you're confused about the subtle differences between `var x = 'blah';` and `x = 'blah'`.  Helpful link to explain that difference: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1471738/445131  It has to do with the scope of the variable being created and destroyed inside the for loop, or persisting through every iteration.  To see this, print out ch on every iteration of the loop.  Defining ch inside or outside the loop has significance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### No Magic involved

```
var i, ch, chars = input.split('');
```

declares the variables `i`, `ch` and `chars` and assigns to `chars` what `input.split('')` returns.

Basically its equivalent to

```
var i; // undefined
var ch; // undefined
var chars = input.split(''); // Array of string
```

This is typically done for the variables to be available across loop iterations (to access previous values).

#### However...

`i` is just the loop varible and could be declared inline as in

```
for (var i = 0; i < chars.length; i++) {
```

`ch` could live inside the loop since it is reassigned in the first statement anyway

```
  for (var i = 0; i < chars.length; i++) {
      var ch = chars.splice(i, 1);
```

which makes the example confusing indeed (one could say it's poorly written)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, but then, why does the algorithm not work anymore when i remove these two?